# Anaconda configuration and debug python in VS Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I'm using VS Code with anaconda and it's python vers. is 3.6.x. I installed python 3.9 on last day. After this my anaconda stability is disturbed. When I started the VS Code it was running "conda activate" command automatically. But now it's not. Also git can't recognize now from terminal. I solved it ctrl+p and then select shell -> git bash. 
But now I have another problem. I was debugging with F5 but now it says

```
cmd /C "C:\Users\Fordev\anaconda3\python.exe c:\Users\Fordev\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher 58000 -- c:\Users\Fordev\Desktop\tkczmkmsi\.vscode\settings.json "
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

after this it waits and then says "`timed out waiting for launcher to connect`" 
Now I removed my python path's from env. variables and system variables. I think now my configuration's are really complicated cause I tried all solves that i saw. 
At the current, my environment variables: 
User variables Path = `C:\Users\Fordev\anaconda3\;C:\Users\Fordev\anaconda3\Scripts`
System variables Path = `C:\Users\Mp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\Fordev\anaconda3\;C:\Users\Fordev\anaconda3\Scripts`

 My launcher Json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Geçerli Dosya",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

My settings Json:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Fordev\\anaconda3\\python.exe"
}
```

How can I stabil configuration VS Code in Anaconda? I can run my python code but I can't debug it. And also for use github I have to change my shell to git bash everytime and I don't want that.
Can anybody tell me what's the problem?

Comment: I noticed that the file you are debugging is "settings.json". Please open the python file and debug it. In addition, for VS Code cannot recognize the "cmd" command, please check whether the system terminal is available in the terminal outside VS Code.

Comment: I'm not debugging settings.json. I don't know why you thought that. I'm debugging my python program file. And when I clicked "F5" for debug it's run this command **/usr/bin/env C:\\Users\\Fordev\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe c:\\Users\\Fordev\\
.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\\pythonFiles\\lib\\python\\debugpy\\launcher 58800
 -- c:\\Users\\Fordev\\Desktop\\solve\\main.py** So it was always running the commands via cmd. But now it can't

Comment: -In the information you provided, "**c:\Users\Fordev\Desktop\tkczmkmsi\.vscode\settings.json**", it means that the file you are debugging is "settings.json". Please try to reload VS Code and debug python file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you provided,

```
"c:\Users\Fordev\Desktop\tkczmkmsi\.vscode\settings.json"
```

it means that the file VS Code is currently debugging is "settings.json".

Please try to reload VS Code, then open the python file and click 'F5' to debug the python file.

[image]